# How to sync calendar events FROM my phone TO an exchange server?

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange

I own a LG P500 which runs Android 2.3. I was able to set up Exchange sync easily, and now I can read/write email from my exchange account and all events registered in Outlook's calendar also appear on my phone's calendar. However when I enter an event on my phone, it does not appear in Outlook as I would like it. Why, and how do I fix this?

Note that I both the calendar and exchange app on my phone are the default stock apps that came with the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new event, you should be able to select which calendar to add the event to. If you select an Exchange-based calendar, the event will be synced to the server. By default the events are created in the phone's local calendar.

Comment: Nice! Didn't notice that! Though it still doesn't appear. Maybe it's just slow, I'll wait for a moment. Btw - can I change the default calendar? I don't see a setting for that in Calendar's options.

Comment: Yay! It synce'd! Although I had to delete and recreate event in the right calendar. Apparently changing the calendar of an existing event messes up synchronization. Well, that's easy enough to work around. :)

Comment: I don't know about LGs stock calendar, but if there is such an option it should be in the calendar settings. Just checked my Galaxy S and apparently that feature has been removed from this version too, used to have it :/